# jQuery contents() when used with 'iframe' , text disappears in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, iframe

I'm trying to make a website, somewhat similar to [jsbin.com](https://jsbin.com).
Here is a snap of how it looks in ...

1. Firefox -
   [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LILYD.png)
2. Chromium - [ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hqnn.png)

---

**Take a look at code !**

```js
$(".toggleButton").hover(function() {

  $(this).addClass("hightlightedButton");

}, function() {

  $(this).removeClass("hightlightedButton");

});


$(".toggleButton").click(function() {

  $(this).toggleClass("active");

  $(this).removeClass("hightlightedButton");

});


$(".panel").height($(window).height() - $("#header").height() - 14);


$(".panel").width(($(window).width() / 2) - 5);

$("iframe").contents().find("html").html($("#htmlPanel").val());
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#header {
  width: 99.2%;
  background: #EEEEEE;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 30px;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 120%;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

#buttonContainer {
  width: 244px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.toggleButton {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 6px;
  border-right: none;
  font-size: 90%
}

#html {
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
}

#output {
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.active {
  background-color: #E8F2FF;
}

.hightlightedButton {
  background-color: grey;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-color: grey;
}

.panel {
  float: left;
}

iframe {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">

  <div id="logo">

    CodePlayer

  </div>

  <div id="buttonContainer">


    <div class="toggleButton active" id="html">HTML</div>

    <div class="toggleButton" id="css">CSS</div>

    <div class="toggleButton" id="javascript">JavaScript</div>

    <div class="toggleButton active" id="output">Output</div>


  </div>

</div>


<div id="bodyContainer">

  <textarea id="htmlPanel" class="panel" name="textarea">Hello World!</textarea>

  <iframe id="outputPanel" class="panel"></iframe>

</div>
```

(*Take a note that when you run the above code with build-in run function of Stack over, the 'iframe' doesn't appear.*)

**Check out exact code : '[Paste Bin](https://pastebin.com/DgQqENLR)'**

---

**Problem Description**

As you can see in *Screenshots* of *Firefox Browser* the `Hello World!` is not visible in the second tab, but in *Screenshots* of *Chromium Browser* can see it (in the second half of screen).

Main Line of code (I think) which needs to edited is in `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` (Tag).

`$("iframe").contents().find("html").html($("#htmlPanel").val());`

How to get the *output* same in *Firefox*, like it's in other browsers (*Chromium*)?

---

***Extra:***
Solutions I tried, that are not working

1. [iframe content disappears on Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9967478/iframe-content-disappears-on-firefox/27948354) (*from stack-overflow*)
2. [Jquery contents() change html for iframe disappear in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27541631/jquery-contents-change-html-for-iframe-disappear-in-firefox) (*from stack-overflow*)